# How do I vary a variable until I end up with a least squares result between a model output and real data?

Tags: python, optimization, model, statistics, least-squares

I am trying to solve a problem where I want to fit a model to real data.  I have a complicated model, let's say f(a, b, c, d, e), which is a function that produces values that should be similar to real life data.  One of the parameters to the model, let's say variable "e", can vary.  "e" a parameter that adjusts the model so that it gets close to real data.

What I want to do, is to have Python choose a "e", so that the squared difference between the values produced by my model and real data are minimized.  In other words, this is the set up:

1. Vector1 = Real life values
2. Vector2 = f(a, b, c, d, e); where a, b, c, d are given already, and e is the only unknown
3. Find e where (Vector2 - Vector1)^2 is minimized

Thanks!

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [scipy.optimize.least_squares](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html#scipy.optimize.least_squares).  You need to provide it with a function that takes a value for `e` and returns the residuals (your `Vector2 - Vector1`) and an initial guess, `x0`. So something like

```
from scipy.optimize import least_squares    

def residuals(e):
  return f(a,b,c,d,e) - vec1

res = least_squares(residuals, x0=0)

res.x  # e value
```

Note that this only guarantees to find a local minimum for `(Vector2 - Vector1)^2`; changing your initial guess can affect what minimum you converge to.